# Unable to convert currency paypal pay API error

Tags: api, paypal, payment, currency, sandbox

I am using paypal adaptive payment API.

> https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/Pay

**Request payload**

```
{
"actionType":"PAY",
"memo":"Example",
"preapprovalKey":"PA-4PV844316B104562R",
"receiverList":{"receiver":{"amount":"14.00","email":"reveiver.email@gmail.com"}},
"currencyCode":"CHF",
"requestEnvelope":{"errorLanguage":"en_US"},
"pinType":"NOT_REQUIRED",
"feesPayer": "SENDER",
"senderEmail":"sender.email@gmail.com",
"returnUrl":"http://www.google.com/?paypal=ok",
"cancelUrl":"http://www.google.com/paypal=cancel",
"clientDetails": {
    "applicationId": "APP-80W284485P789543T"
}
}
```

**Getting response**

```
    {
    "responseEnvelope": {
        "timestamp": "2018-11-05T20:45:14.602-08:00",
        "ack": "Failure",
        "correlationId": "1609b946b9c72",
        "build": "50069244"
    },
    "error": [
        {
            "errorId": "520002",
            "domain": "PLATFORM",
            "subdomain": "Application",
            "severity": "Error",
            "category": "Application",
            "message": "Internal Error",
            "parameter": [
                "Unable to convert currency"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

If I send currencyCode:"USD" then it work fine But when i pass currencyCode:"CHF" Then it gives error in response. My all sandbox account currency is CHF. Till 26th Oct it's working but suddenly gives error when i check on 3rd Nov.

Comment: The issue is now fixed by PayPal dev team. This has been an issue from their end. i directly messaged them via twitter and got a reply that they worked on it and it's now fixed. I had also shared this link my message but i feel sorry that we couldn't bring the conversation to this thread. Anyway you can try now and it works perfectly fine.

Comment: Yeah, it's working now.

Answer (score 0):

Base on my debugging, it happens when you have more than one receiver, currency is not USD and `reverseAllParallelPaymentsOnError` is set to true.

When `reverseAllParallelPaymentsOnError`  is set to false, the transaction is pushing through.

Not a solution though, I'm still checking for other solution.

Comment: Hello @Joseph I need to send only one receiver and my currency is CHF. Is there any solution for a single receiver?

Comment: Hi @Jayesh, I think the issue is with in paypal sandbox, I've created a request again and it's now working.